# Nomes e tipos de dados Lua

Tags: lua

Sobre nomes e tipos de dados na linguagem Lua. Qual é o tamanho máximo de um nome? É permitida a definição de tipos Enumeração, Subfaixa, Registro e União? Não encontrei essas informações na documentação.

Comment: Com "nome" você quer dizer nome de variável/função?

Comment: Sim, variável/classe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Qual é o tamanho máximo de um nome?**

Lua não possui um tamanho máximo para os nomes de variável. Internamente, basicamente os nomes são só strings.

**Possui o tipo Enumeração?**

Hoje ainda não suporta enumerações por padrão. Existem bibliotecas que tentam criar algo parecido como o [lua-enum](https://github.com/stefano-m/lua-enum), ou você pode também simplesmente criar uma table:

```
local dias_da_semana = {
    ["SEGUNDA"] = 1,
    ["TERÇA"] = 2,
    -- ...
}

print(dias_da_semana.SEGUNDA) -- E então usar desta forma
```

Mas como esperado, não terá o mesmo comportamento de uma enumeração de verdade.

**Possui o tipo Subfaixa?**

Não, na linguagem não tem nada pronto para isso também.

**Possui o tipo Registro?**

Também não. O mais próximo que você vai conseguir é usando as tables, que podem servir com registros dinâmicos:

```
local registro = {
    x = 1,
    y = nil
}
```

**Possui o tipo União**

Não! E acho que nem faz muito sentido em uma linguagem com tipagem dinâmica. :v